# How to save UIWebView content for offline display?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, offline

I'm using Xcode 7.2 and Swift to create an iOS app, on this app I display the content of my website, however if I was offline the content will not be shown. So I want to cache the webpage and display for offline.

After I declared everything I'm using the following code :

```
    var URLPATH="http://google.com"

    let requestURL = NSURL(string: URLPATH)

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requestURL!)

    WB.loadRequest(request)
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve this problem? It would really help me.

Comment: I would like an answer to this as well. Need to do the same, but it's horrible finding a good repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. HTML to Data

```
if let url = URL(string: urlString) {
   person.setValue(try? Data(contentsOf: url), forKey: "content_article")
}
```

> 2. Data to WebView

```
if let savedObject = fetchedObjects?.first,
   let data = savedObject.content_article as? Data,
   let baseStringUrl = savedObject.content_url,
   let baseURL = URL(string: baseStringUrl) {

   webView.load(
     data, mimeType: "text/html", 
     textEncodingName: "", 
     baseURL: baseURL
  )
}
```